# Error while setting time format unable to set the numberformat property of the range class

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Below code return exception as `unable to set the numberformat property of the range class`

```
currentWorkSheet.Columns[6].NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM";
```

It works fine if OS Region and TimeZone is set to `India` but fails for `Sweden`. Some where I read that for Netherlands we need to use `u:mm:ss` instead of `h:mm:ss`. Does that mean I have to write condtion for each time zone or is there any other way?

Comment: Not sure how to do access in your application, but in Excel VBA, the `Application.International` properties include the strings being used for the time (and date) components. They are in the Windows Regional Settings for the particular computer.

Comment: I have an Excel Add-In written in C# @ron-rosenfeld

Comment: Again: **Not sure how to do access in your application**.  You'll have to figure that out..

Comment: Thanks, above comment was helpful.

Comment: As per this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international I have to get code for each moth,day, year,hour, minutes, seconds. Can I get the complete time format used in local system?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way of doing it other than individually.

Comment: You also need to access the date and time separators.

Comment: Replaced all `mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss` by code obtained from Application.International and after adding `.000 AM/PM` assigned to number format but still getting same error. I also used separators from Application.International

Comment: There is likely an issue in your coding.  What is the format string you are getting? Does that same string still work if you copy/paste into the cell?  Does it work without the AM/PM?